# Pointers in C with OpenMP

Tags: c

Let's say I have this small part of a program:

```
#pragma omp parallel for collapse(2)
for(ix = 2; ix <= sizep ; ix++){
 for(iy = 2; iy <= sizep ; iy++){
    *(u1+ix*size+iy)=*(u2+ix*size+iy)+*(u2+ix+iy);
 }
}
```

I am sure the variable left of operator `=` is "write" so there is problem if two threads access this part of memory. But what about `*(u2+ix*size+iy)`, is that part write also? I mean does this move pointer `u2` to the correct memory address and then read this position? In short is this safe for parallel use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right about the "write" part. Even protecting write by locking mechansims would fail in that case if the destination is the same since values are overwritten

But, for the "read" part, you can always read the same memory address concurrently (in parallel threads), of course!

In your sample code, all computations performed to determine the read address are done without using any write to global variables (actually it does not use any locals, even if that wouldn't be a problem) or call non-thread safe methods so computing the address is completely thread-safe (uses function-local/auto memory).

I hope it answers your question.